# Pipe stalls with I/O redirection

Tags: linux, windows, pipe, rexx

We're trying to add a capability to the ooRexx programming language that allows the programmer to issue an operating system command with the option of I/O redirection on the stdin, stdout, and stderr streams. We'doing this for both Windows and all unix-based systems.

We have the setup for both environments, and the setup is largely the same:

1. create the appropriate pipes for the requested redirection.
2. launch a new process to process the command.
3. Write the input data to the stdin pipe.
4. Read from the stdout pipe, then read from the stderr pipe.

We're running into stall issues when there's a large amount of data being written to the input pipe and also a large amount of output data. If, while writing to stdin and the pipe is full, we get blocked. However, if the launched process also manages to fill the output pipe up, it blocks too. As a result, the entire pipeline stalls and everything hangs.  Our code is stuck trying to write to the input pipe until some data is read from it. The process is stuck trying to write to the output pipe until some data is read, which is not going to happen because the write to the input is stalled. A classic deadly embrace.

I've researched a lot of different options for non-blocking I/O on both Windows and Linux, but so far, have not found anything that does not cause other problems, such as lost data. Does anybody have any suggestions on how this can be managed?

For the interested, here is a link to the code that handles the Windows end of this:

https://sourceforge.net/p/oorexx/code-0/HEAD/tree/sandbox/rick/addresswith/interpreter/platform/windows/SystemCommands.cpp

and here is the Linux version

https://sourceforge.net/p/oorexx/code-0/HEAD/tree/sandbox/rick/addresswith/interpreter/platform/unix/SystemCommands.cpp

Comment: Why have you tagged this rexx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like python [documents a similar type of deadlock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) in its documentation. It seems like [python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py) (see around line 900 and the `_communicate`) handles this by **creating multiple reader daemon threads** that reads from the output pipe whilst writing to the input pipe when the `communicate` method is called.

Though this type of construct is done for a higher level language (Python), I think creating threads that would read the output pipes while at the same time writing to the input pipe within the main program would be a good way to go. Although, I haven't really used threads in C++/C, so I can't really vouch for its efficiency or any possible pitfalls when using threads.

A problem I might see with using multiple threads (as always) is you would have to make sure to account for any possible data races by putting the appropriate synchronization code.

Comment: On Windows at least, I've managed to get this working by spinning off a thread for the input side. Have yet to try this on Linux.

Comment: This is the canonical answer to "run an OS command" problems.  Unless your programming environment does it for you, you always wind up creating separate execution environments (threads, processes, whatever it takes) to feed STDIN to the command and consume STDOUT and STDERR.